# Reading PDF files using PHP

Tags: php

I have been new to the PHP development area and I am working on a small project. In one of the requirement, after the user logs in with a unique ID, I need to search a series a PDF's and if the login ID matches with the corresponding PDF file I need to fetch that and display that. 
I have created the login form and stored the details in the database. (Here the user and the pdf have the same name to make things easy)

Now I have got a couple of questions:

1. How can I call the PDF files, does it make sense to store them in the database or just put all the pdfs in the folder and call them from there (if so how I can do it).
2. After getting the pdf, it should be displayed.

Any valuable information regarding this would be really helpful.

Regards
Raks

Comment: `After getting the pdf, it should be displayed` - Is this a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not read the pdf for the purpose as you mentioned that to search the pdf among all the files., and just display that.
for this you can directly display the pdf in the browser itself by just redirecting to the address of the pdf file., and the browsers automatically displays the pdf..

Only you need to do is that, searching for the appropriate file., for this you said the login id should match with the pdf name.., you use the function file_get_contents() which returns boolean when used in a if case and check whether pdf with particular name is available and then if available redirect the user, or else tell him that its not available..

Comment: instead of file_get_contents(), you can actually use fopen()

Comment: @Vishnu: I followed your tip and checked to see whether the .pdf file exists or not. It works good, now I want to redirect the user using header function but still I could not see any changes.

Comment: this is how im redirecting
               if (file_exists($file)) {
                echo 'File found <br />';
                $url = 'Location:http://localhost/testing/' + $file;
                header($url);}

Comment: if i'm not wrong you must be getting a error saying "headers already sent" or something like that.. the thing is, when yu are using the header() function to redirect, yu should not use a echo before that function. i.e., there should be no output displayed before you use the redirection using header function.. Remove the echo'file found'; line.. then it should work all  fine for you..

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it is useless. Just put all PDFs in a folder.
2. Link the users to the .pdf file